# What is wrong with this array input code in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to make a code for making a 2D array from keyboard input to use it in a program. I cannot find any issue in my code but it doesn't work properly. Could you explain? I need a solution as simple as possible as I'm still a beginner.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n,m;
cin >> n;
cin >> m;
int s[n-1][m-1];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
    cin >> s[i][j];
  }
}
//Test by printing out the elements
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<m; j++){
    cout << s[i][j] << " ";
  }
}
```

Input:

```
3 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2
```

Output:

```
 1 2 3 5 5 6 7 9 9 0 1 2
```

Element s[0][3] equals s[1][0] and s[1][3] equals s[2][0]. How??

Comment: You have an off-by-one error here: `int s[n-1][m-1]`.  This should be `int s[n][m];`

Comment: Wait what is exactly is n in s[n], the number of elements or the last index?

Comment: When you declare an array `int s[n]`, it has `n` elements.  The indexes range from `0` to `n-1`

Comment: This `int s[n-1][m-1];` is simply not valid C++. The dimensions of arrays in C++ must be compile-time constants.

Comment: If m is number of elements why are s[2][0] to s[2][m-1]  correctly defined?

Comment: Probably not your issue:  Sorry, this is not std C++ compliant.  g++ will probably handle your code as a language extension, but array dimensions must be compile-time-constants,  For C++, you can consider dynamic allocation.  Plenty of examples in SO.

Comment: @Bluberry17 Note that the c++ standard doesn't support variable length arrays anyways. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Call me stupid but... what are compile-time-constants?

Comment: @Blub `4` or `const int n = 4;`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oh ok. Got it.

Comment: @Bluberry17 -- Stop doing this stuff and stuff that looks like this:`int s[n][m];`  That should always be `std::vector<std::vector<int>> s(n, std::vector<int>(m));`, unless you are great at handling dynamic allocation using `new[]\delete[]` (and even if you are great, use vector), or if `n` and `m` are compile-time constants.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have you rows and columns mixed up. You have `s[i][j]` when it should be `s[j][i]`.Also, as far as `int s[n-1][m-1];` goes, I believe that you're initializing this wrong. While an array starts at index 0 and goes to index (size - 1), when you initialize it, it should be `array[enteredSize]`, not `array[enteredSize - 1]`. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work. I think what Peter Ruderman said in the comment is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, after I just tested your code, I noticed that error as well and edited my answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I just started taking programming classes and this is something I had not understood correctly.